# How can I write a statelesswidget?

Tags: flutter-widget

I had just started learning flutter and I face a problem that now trying to solve it for three days.
Hope someone can help me.

The problem is that when I am trying to write a stateless widget, it should appear a short cut for it and click enter so it will automatic fill in all the code, but when I press enter it doesn't complete the code it only shows the word that I had written 'StatelessWidget' and of course it shows error with the red pulp.

Comment: U can type 'stless' for shortcut in Android Studio

Comment: I did and it show the options but when I click enter on the option that I choose nothing come. Please help me in this matter.